# I have a problem the form works but it does not send me the emails could you help me It is my first publication,

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-forms

> 

I have a problem the form works but it does not send me the emails could you help me  It is my first publication, I honestly have no idea what it could be

[**CODE SETTINGS**]

```
EMAIL_BACKEND='django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST='smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_USE_TLS=True
EMAIL_PORT=587
EMAIL_HOST_USER='xxxxx@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'**
```

> 

[** CODE VIEWS **]

```
    from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
    from .forms import FormularioContacto
    from django.conf import settings
    from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
    
    # Create your views here.
    def contacto(request):
        form=FormularioContacto()
    
        if request.method == "POST":
            form=FormularioContacto(data=request.POST)
    
            if form.is_valid():
                nombre=request.POST.get("nombre")
                email=request.POST.get("email")
                contenido=request.POST.get("contenido")
    
              
                email= EmailMessage(f"Alguien quiere contactarse desde la WEB,El Usuario: {nombre} con el email: {email} por el asunto: {contenido}","",["torresfdev@gmail.com"],reply_to=[email])
                email.send()
                try:
                    
                    return redirect("/contacto/?Enviadoconexito")
                except:
                    return redirect ("/contacto/?NO_se_pudo_enviar")
                
                
        return render (request,"contactoapp/contacto.html", {"form":form})
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are using the wrong `email function`

in django [email documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/email/), they recommend using `send_mail`

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail

send_mail(
    'Subject here',
    'Here is the message.',
    'from@example.com',
    ['to@example.com'],
    fail_silently=False,
)
```

and also check if your gmail account allows access to less secured apps ([less secured app access in gmail](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en))